# VueJS 3: How to inject JS script into index.html with "Type" as "text/javascript"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

I currently build and deploy my VueJS webapp (created via vue3 cli) in a http2 service in aws ec2.

Before deploying, I run  `npm run build` which is package.json as `"build": vue-cli-service build`

Most of the times, the deployment to aws ec2 is good and webpage loads fine in public internet.

Sometimes, I have following error

> ```
> Warning: The script from "https:/websitedomain.com/js/chunk-vendors.sdadd234.js" was loaded even though its MIME type ("text/html") is not a valid Javascript MIME type.
>
> Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
> ```

**Result**

The webpage is blank white page with no data.

**Some investigation**

Found that Vue injects js and css files into my public/index.html" and when i see "View page source" on blank page, it has code like `<script src="/js/chunk-vendors.sdadd234.js">`

I am thinking if I can find a way to add "text/javascript" then the page would load just fine.

Has anyone faced this error before? How to solve this problem?

Comment: "text/javascript" is not needed in HTML5 for loading JS as it is a default. From the error message it seems your server is returning 404 and some HTML when that chunk is requested - next time it happens, do not check the page source but look on Network tab for any 404 responses...

Comment: Thanks Michal, I checked network tab and did not notice any issue (HTTP 200). But will keep an eye. Seems this error is no longer occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others that end up in this situation

I did not see this problem any more. Only thing I changed is how the build and deployment stages are in my website development.

**Previously**

1. Code changes
2. `npm run serve` - to verify everything looks good in local
3. `npm run build` and `git commit .` - This steps is to generate those build files(compressed js, css..) in `dist`
4. After `git push`, my settings in AWS pipelines take care of updating files in `dist` directory to all my EC2 hosts service the website.

** New process **

1. Code changes
2. `npm run serve` - to verify everything looks good in local
3. `git commit .` - No build phase
4. `git push`
5. Now i have update my AWS pipelines to have 3 step process (Code, `build` and deploy to EC2 hosts)